# BeautifulSoup - scraping other pages if there is no change in link or href available

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if there is any way to **scrape** website with pagination. After switching the page nothing changes. The link remains the same, "A" tag has no href with new link etc. This is how selector looks like: "a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page.number, $event)" class="ng-binding">2</a"

Appreciate for any hints.

Comment: You might be better off using [Selenium](https://selenium.dev), if you have to deal with JavaScript. Can you include more of your code? What did you do to click that button?

Comment: I do not need to click anything. I need to scrap data from website. I need to switch between pages.

Comment: What do you mean by _After switching the page nothing changes_? Could you expand on your question as a whole?

Comment: Usualy when u go to the next page the navigation link changes - page number or something similar appears in html link so u know on which page you are currently. In my case nothing changes and I have no idea how to make beautifulsoup to scrap next pages.

Comment: Ah, it’s probably using JavaScript then. Sometimes changing pages/loading more items/etc. involves an API call to get the content, maybe that’s the case here? It really depends on the website though, can you share more of the HTML source, or an example web page?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile just checked the website in dev tools and it's api indeed. Here is the link: https://booksy.com/pl-pl/17101_barber-shop-brooklyn_barber-shop_13750_wroclaw

Comment: Great! Have you taken a look at the call itself using the networking inspector thingy (I forget what’s it called)?

Comment: this page use JavaScript/XHR to get data for next page - it uses url like https://booksy.com/api/pl/2/customer_api/businesses/17101/reviews?reviews_page=2&reviews_per_page=5 and there is `reviews_page=2` which you can change to get next pages. And this url get data as JSON file which you can easily convert to Python's dictionary, and get data from dictionary instead of scraping from HTML.

Comment: BTW: this page uses JavaScript to put some elements on page but beautifulsoup can't run JavaScript.

Comment: next time put URL in question - it is very useful information. (PL: następnym razem umieść URL w pytaniu - to jest bardzo użyteczna informacja)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change page then it uses `JavaScript/XHR/AJAX` to get data as JSON from url

https://booksy.com/api/pl/2/customer_api/businesses/17101/reviews?reviews_page=2&reviews_per_page=5

It also uses header `'X-Api-Key'` to send API key.

You can change `reviews_page=2` to get data for othere pages. You can even get data for first page.

You can easily convert JSON to Python's dictionary and you will not have to scrape from HTML

---

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Api-Key': 'web-e3d812bf-d7a2-445d-ab38-55589ae6a121'
}

url = 'https://booksy.com/api/pl/2/customer_api/businesses/17101/reviews?reviews_page={}&reviews_per_page=5'

for x in range(1, 6):
    print('--- page:', x, '---')

    r = requests.get(url.format(x), headers=headers)
    data = r.json()

    for item in data['reviews']:
        print(item['user']['first_name'])
        print('>', item['review'])
        print('---')
```